# Casting a Function Pointer

Tags: c, casting, function-pointers

If I have a prototype that is declared as:

```
void foo(int (*fi)(void *, void *))
```

And I call the function with something like this:

```
foo(int (*)(void*, void*)(bool_expr ? func1 : func2));
```

Where func1 and func2 are defined as follows:

```
int func1(char *s1, char *s2);
int func2(int *i1, int *i2);
```

Is the function call casting one of the functions (func1 ^ func2) to the type of the function required by foo? Could I also make the prototype for foo look like:

```
void foo(int (*)(void *, void *))
```

Comment: What does this sign ^ should mean?

Comment: The ^ is my short hand for XOR, since you will be casting one function or the other, but not both, and not none. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: I'm not sure that would compile.

Comment: Can you give an example of where this would be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented the code as posted did not compile.

FWIW, this compiles and executes as you would expect with VC2010:

```
int func1(char *s1, char *s2) { printf("func1\n"); return 0; }
int func2(int *i1, int *i2)   { printf("func2\n"); return 0; }

void foo(int (*)(void *, void *));

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    foo(2 == argc ? (int(*)(void*,void*))func1 :
                    (int(*)(void*,void*))func2);

    return 0;
}

void foo(int (*a)(void *, void *))
{
    a((void*)0, (void*)0);
}
```

Comment: Note that this code invokes undefined behavior. 6.5.2.2(9) says that the function pointer type must be compatible with the actual function. 6.7.5.3(15) says that functions are compatible if they have compatible return types and compatible parameter types. But `char*` is not compatible with `int*` because 6.7.5.1(2) says that pointer types are compatible if they are identically qualified and are pointers to compatible types, and `char` is not compatible with `int`. [There exists at least one real machine where `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*)`.]

Answer (score 2):

According to C specification, casting function pointers results in unspecified behavior, but many compilers (e.g. gcc) do what you expect them to do, because function pointer is just an address in memory. Just to be safe, I would re-declare func1 and func2 to take void*, and then cast these pointers to char* and int* as required.

Comment: casting function pointers doesn't result in UB. calling a function through an incompatible pointer type does result in UB.

Comment: That's not quite what the C standard says.  Calling a function via a pointer that has a type that's incompatible with the function's actual type has undefined (not merely unspecified) behavior.  Casting a function pointer to any pointer-to-function type is valid, as long as the type used in any call is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In GCC, this expression:

```
bool_expr ? func1 : func2
```

gives this warning:

```
warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression
```

even if you don't turn on special warnings.

What's more, GCC resolves this pointer-type mismatch by casting both expressions to `void *`; so then, when you try to cast it back (either explicitly, with `(int (*)(void*, void*))`, or implicitly, by passing it to `foo`), it gives this warning:

```
warning: ISO C forbids conversion of object pointer to function pointer type
```

if you enable pedantry. (The reason that ISO C forbids this is that a function pointer does not have to be implemented, internally, as a pointer to a memory location, so it may not have the same size and whatnot as a regular "object" pointer.)

That said, this:

```
foo((bool_expr ? (int (*)(void*, void*))func1 : (int (*)(void*, void*))func2));
```

should be relatively safe, provided that `foo` is passing valid `char` pointers to `func1` or valid `int` pointers to `func2`.

And I would guess that, on a system where function pointers are truly incompatible with `void *`, a compiler wouldn't resolve the mismatch `bool_expr ? func1 : func2` in favor of `void *` (though I haven't consulted the spec on this).